# Working example of a Singleton

Tags: singleton

In C#, I want to implement Singletons to provide data in one thread to many other threads.

I have decided to use this lazy form of Singleton from Jon Skeet (thanks, Jon!):

```java
public sealed class Singleton
{
    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return Nested.instance;
        }
    }

    class Nested
    {
        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static Nested()
        {
        }

        internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }
}
```

So far, so good. ... but how does one use that?

What I want to do is share a single instance of the following data:

```java
public bool   myboolean   = false ;
public double mydoubles[] = new double[128,3] ;
public IntPtr myhandles[] = new IntPtr[128]   ;
```

How do I declare and reference these data as Singletons?

I also need them to be referenceable across different namespaces.

Many thanks!

Comment: 1) If you want to create a singleton, why use that overly verbose syntax.  Jon's article provides a syntax that's shorter and equally effective. 2) You almost certainly don't want to be doing this at all; trying to access these objects from different threads is likely going to result in unsafe code filled with race conditions.

Comment: Is this the version you mean:

 public sealed class Singleton
 {
  private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

  static Singleton()
  {
  }

  private Singleton()
  {
  }

  public static Singleton Instance
  {
   get
   {
    return instance;
   }
  }
 }

I'm happy to do that, but my main requirement is to have a unique instance of the data I mentioned above available to multiple threads. If you can suggest a good and effective way (with a coded example) to do that, I would be most grateful. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, I am also limited to .NET 3.5 at this time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    // thread-safety
    public sealed class Singleton
    {
        private static Singleton instance = null;
        private static readonly object padlock = new object();

        private bool myboolean = false;
        private double[,] mydoubles = new double[128, 3];
        private IntPtr[] myhandles = new IntPtr[128];

        Singleton()
        {
        }

        public static Singleton Instance
        {
            get
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new Singleton();
                    }
                    return instance;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and to access

```
        //Singleton.Instance.myboolean
        //Singleton.Instance.mydoubles
        //Singleton.Instance.myhandles
```

Comment: Many thanks! I'm currently testing it and will let you know how it goes. Very much appreciate your advice.

Comment: This seems to be working well enough. Thanks. However, is it possible to test if the instance has been created by another thread, by using a comparison to null, for example, so as to avoid actually instantiating it? My tests seem to indicate it is not. On the other hand, is there a way to ensure the instance is created only by a particular thread ... which probably means explicit instantiation rather than lazy?

Comment: Or can one dispose of an instance somehow to allow another to be created?

Comment: @jeronymite as we are using a lock in a object, other threads can't access that part of code, until the thread that blocked that part release the lock. So, when a thread tries to access that block locked by another thread, when it will access (after release the lock), there will be already an instance of your class.

Comment: Understood, Thiago. Thanks. I face an additional problem in that the threads that will access the code can come from different namespaces and so the Singleton is qualified by a namespace. What I am finding is that if the Singleton is instantiated by a thread in one namespace, even though I fully qualify the Singleton with the namespace, it appears that a second Singleton in the other namespace is possible. Perhaps that indicates a flaw in my code, but I've tried to be as thorough as possible in always referring to the Singleton as a fully namespace-qualified object. Your thoughts?

Comment: If I understood what you want, the best option is use Dependency Injection (which you can say to use Singleton pattern). Reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/254091/Implementing-Microsoft-Unity-Design-Pattern

Comment: A brief overview of what I'm trying to do may help. I have a "master" thread that manages "master data" for all other threads. It sits in its own namespace. In a different namespace, "worker" threads generate master data to be managed by the master. They also receive configuration data from the master. Worker threads are created/destroyed as required. They can exist in the absence of the master, which may likewise be created/destroyed as required. If the master is present, all master data is managed by it. If the master is absent, workers perform other tasks until the master returns.

Comment: Why master could be release? In which case?

Comment: Apologies, Tiago. I'm not sure if I understand the question. Nevertheless, the master and the workers can all be started and stopped as required at any time. Consequently, the thread that instantiates could be the master or any of the workers. It is not important which thread instantiates, so long as master and all workers can access the data. However, what I'm finding is that sometimes, dumping the data as seen by all threads shows some threads with all zero data and some with correctly populated data, implying different instantiations.

Comment: @jeronymite send me one e-mail. thxplode at gmail. It's a little hard to understand your scenario.